# Toast Message for Android Activity Lifecycle Methods

Tags: android, android-studio, activity-lifecycle, android-toast

I've got this task to do:
"Create an Android Project with Android Studio. For each  Android Activity Lifecycle Methods, instead of just Logging(Log.i etc), show a Toast Message."
but I never used Android Studio before, could someone of you just show me an example how to do something like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for a good tutorial on the web.

[Here is](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS1QulWo1RIbb1cYyzZpLFCKvdYV_yJ-E) video lessons how to install Android Studio and build first application.

And [here is](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) the official text instruction from Google.